# fileupload and backbone.js + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, multipart

I managed to create a small app that uses backbone.js for CRUD process.
Now i am trying to include file upload as well in "Create". i m using "paperclip" to upload image. As i am learning about backbone.js please tell me some approach to making it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with backbone models. You will have to create a form (including the file field) on the client side and post form to the server.

You can use something like that on the client:
http://www.williambharding.com/blog/rails/rails-ajax-image-uploading-made-simple-with-jquery/

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out the [jquery.iframe.transport](http://cmlenz.github.com/jquery-iframe-transport/) plugin. Since you're using rails 3, you can use [remotipart](https://github.com/leppert/remotipart) instead (it bundles the iframe.transport plugin), which hooks into rails's ujs driver to automatically add support for file upload in ajax requests.